# What is going on in this CSS? Can someone tell me what kind of CSS this is?

Tags: css

I happened to be looking at the DOM for a Yahoo page to block an ad. I need the ID for this. In examining the CSS, I see this:

```
class="List(n) P(0) My(12px) stream-grid_Mb(0) Fz(11px) C(--grey-hair) Whs(nw) stream-realted-list D(f)"
```

Is this `Less`?

I'm still using the "old fashioned" way of writing out my CSS. I never did see the advantage to using Less or any equivalent. I would be interested to know what the advantages are to using Less, or even something like what I'm seeing in Yahoo's HTML, over writing CSS and including them in the HTML.

Thank you

Comment: This isn't special CSS, those are just names of classes, e.g. `List(n)` or `P(0)`, and some type of build tool automatically generates class names that correlate to the class name. This is the basis of frameworks like TailwindCSS.

Comment: Thanks. Why would they do this? What is the advantage to all the obfuscation?

Comment: The advantage is that you get to put your element’s style information in your HTML. And if that doesn’t seem like an advantage to you, well, I agree.

Comment: @code I just went to TailwindCSS and see what it does. If you want to post your comment as your answer, I'll accept for you. Thanks again

Comment: @Ry- It honestly doesn't seem like it's worth the hassle. I mean, I usually have all my CSS divided up by page when needed, but the system I've been using for years has never failed me yet. This is like that Less, correct?

Comment: No, this is not really like Less (although you could use Less approximately like this, but it’d still be just as bad), apart from also having CSS output and involving a preprocessing step.

Comment: @Ry- Ok. Let me ask you. Also, same question. Is Less worth using over writing traditional CSS?

Comment: That’s pretty subjective. I personally use Sass (a Less equivalent) when there’s already a build step for some reason, but if not, CSS variables go a long way.